# Ошибочный результат метода с использованием DateFormat Java

Tags: java, время

При использовании метода ниже возвращается false, даже когда введено верное значение в ячейку JTable. 
В чем может быть ошибка?

```
boolean checkTime(JTable table,int indexRow,int indexColOfValue){//возвращает правильность формата необходимого столбца времени

                TableModel tableModel= table.getModel(); //используем модель таблицы

                     TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Moscow");

                        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                        dateFormat.setLenient(false);


                        try {
                             dateFormat.parse(tableModel.getValueAt(indexRow, indexColOfValue).toString());
                        } catch (ParseException e) {

                        return false;
                        }



                return true;

            }
```

Результат, после установки вывода значения ячейки перед parse():

```
14:12:40 // прошло
11:15:60 // не прошло по условию
11:15:60 // должно пройти, так как менял значение на верное
11:15:60 // должно пройти, так как менял значение на верное
```

Вызов данного метода в лисенере:

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).

        setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(txtFld){
            @Override
            public boolean stopCellEditing() {
                System.out.println("DefaultCellEditor "+ row+" "+col);
                if(!checkTime(table, col, row)){

                                    return false;

                }

                else return true; 

            }

        });
```

Comment: Перед парсингом даты сделайте `System.out.println(tableModel.getValueAt(indexRow, indexColOfValue).toString())` и покажите, что будет выведено на консоль.

Comment: @post_zeew
добавил, после ошибочного значения- не меняется. Может, проблема в лисенере? (тоже добавлю)

Comment: Что за `txtFld` передается в `DefaultCellEditor` и где оно используется внутри?

Comment: @iksuy данный адаптер можно использовать только передавая в параметрах JTextField, JCombobox или JCheakBox.В него передается значение с используемой ячейки. Этот тэкстфилд больше нигде не использовал так как переделывать метод нет смысла- так как он используется и в других лисенерах без  тэкстфилдов

Comment: @iksuy но это к вопросу не относится, как я понимаю- в методе используется одно и то же "фэловое" значение (не обнуляется). Как можно осуществить проверку НОВОГО значения?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Данные в модель попадают только после завершения `stopCellEditing`, поэтому проверять надо содержимое компонента редактора:

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(new JTextField()) {
    @Override
    public boolean stopCellEditing() {
        if ( !checkTime( ((JTextField)getComponent()).getText() ) ) {
            return false;
        }
        // родительский метод уведомляет таблицу о завершении редактирования
        // можно вызвать отдельно fireEditingStopped()
        return super.stopCellEditing();
    }
});
```

Comment: Разве значение true не уведомляет таблицу о завершении редактирования?
И что дает отдельное использование fireEditingStopped()?
Есть какие-то преимущества от вызова от вызова родительского метода?

Comment: `fireEditingStopped()` сообщает слушателям, что редактирование закончено. Одним из слушателей является сам `JTable`, который в ответ на событие достает из редактора новое значение, помещает в модель и убирает редактор. Без этого (или вызова `super.stopCellEditing()`, который вызывает `fireEditingStopped()`) у меня вообще ничего не работает. Более того, код обработки нажатия на enter в `DefaultCellEditor.EditorDelegate.actionPerformed` вообще игнорирует возвращаемое значение.